# Jenkinsfile not building image from within a dind container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following step of a `Jenkinsfile` stage that is initiated in a `kubernetes` `jenkins` and run from within a `dind` container (therefore the `docker` daemon is present)

```
    steps {
      echo 'building staging image'
      script {
        env.VERSION = readFile 'alerta/ci/ALERTA_BASE_VERSION'
      }
        echo "Bulding with alerta base version: ${env.VERSION}"
        sh 'docker build --tag alerta-local --build-arg ALERTA_BASE_VERSION=${env.VERSION} alerta-custom'
    }
  }
```

The `echo "Bulding with alerta base version: ${env.VERSION}"` is apparently executed, given that I see in the `jenkins` console:

```
21:55:57  Bulding with alerta base version: 8.0.2
```

However the pipeline ultimately fails with the following error:

```
21:55:59  /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/ebhook-pipeline_alerta_dev_infra@tmp/durable-606e41f8/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/ebhook-pipeline_alerta_dev_infra@tmp/durable-606e41f8/script.sh: Bad substitution
```

What am I missing?

Is there a more "elegant" way of building images in a `Jenkinsfile` given that I want to pass `--build-arg` during the built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is raised because `${env.VERSION}` is not a valid environment variable. Double quotes should be used to make Jenkins evaluate that variable and pass the evaluated value to the `sh` step:

```
sh "docker build --tag alerta-local --build-arg ALERTA_BASE_VERSION=${env.VERSION} alerta-custom"
```